# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evlauating 'newData[0].flag')

Tags: javascript, react-native, typeerror

I integrated a dependency called rn-country-picker and used in my react native app. It was working fine before but now it throws the error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evlauating 'newData[0].flag')." I can not figure out the exact reason for the error.

The section where I used the library has the following code:

```
{/* COuntry */}

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>Select your country</Text>

        <CountryPicker
          disable={false}
          animationType={"fade"}
          containerStyle={styles.pickerStyle}
          pickerTitleStyle={styles.pickerTitleStyle}
          selectedCountryTextStyle={styles.selectedCountryTextStyle}
          countryNameTextStyle={styles.countryNameTextStyle}
          pickerTitle={"Select your country"}
          searchBarPlaceHolder={"Search......"}
          hideCountryFlag={false}
          hideCountryCode={false}
          searchBarStyle={styles.searchBarStyle}
          countryCode={this.state.mCountryCode}
          selectedValue={this._selectedValue}
        />
      </View>
```

It is a dependency by Vishal Dhanotiya and you can find the code here from this url: https://github.com/vishaldhanotiya/rn-country-picker/blob/master/index.js

It shows the error at line 84. I have only removed the props from the component and other than that I have not touched any of the other code. It was fine before but out of nowhere it is throwing this error. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, it gives the exception because you are accessing `newData` like an array and It could have a boolean value in it.

```
const newData = CountryJSON.filter(function (item) {
      const itemData = item.callingCode;
      const textData = defaultText;
      return itemData === textData; // it is returning boolean value here either true or false
    });

    return (
      <View>
        ........
          {hideCountryFlag ? null : (
            <Image
              source={{uri: newData[0].flag}} // It is an exception because it's either tru or false not array of course
              style={styles.countryFlagContainer}
            />
          )}
          ......
      </View>
    );
```

Comment: Can you please help me fix this issue @Nooruddin